# SSIS - connection to new database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssis

I am new to SSIS so the question might seem simple. What I'm trying to do is to extract data from a source and load it into a new database which should be created in the process (not beforehand). I create that DB using Execute SQL task. However I encounter a problem as I'm unable to connect to that DB using data destination because DB does not exist at that moment.

Can you please help me with ideas how to solve this problem? Or maybe there is any other way how to create the kind of package I described?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create db first in your sql server and then point to that db in destination connection. And map the columns with your source query or table with your destination table.

Answer (score 0):

In your requirement you are asking to extract data from suppose Database1 and copy that data in database2. And this should be done during execution of SSIS package.
For this you need to use Execute SQL Task for Destination also.

For example:

Create database Database2;
Insert into Database2.TableName
Select * from Database1.TableName